# How can i use Javascript to remove extra decimal places?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript that finds numbers on a page and multiples them by 10, it only changes numbers inside a class called change number eg:

```
<b class="multiplyit">0.69</b>
```

I use the following javascript to acheive this:

```
var multiplyBy = 10 ;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('multiplyit');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML *= multiplyBy;
}
```

However sometimes this gives me numbers with a lot of decimal points eg.
23.32324334345343434
I would like to restrict these numbers, i have tried using

```
num.toFixed(2);
```

However i can seem to get it work work correctly
eg:

```
var multiplyBy = 10 ;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('multiplyit');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML *= multiplyBy;
num.toFixed(2);
}
```

I know i have not added numtofixed properly, i am guessing i need to add it to a variable but i can not figure out which one (new to javascript)
How can i acheive this?

Comment: in your last code, where is `num` declared ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that

```
  elements[i].innerHTML = (elements[i].innerHTML * multiplyBy).toFixed(2);
```

No need to declare an extra variable

Comment: "*No need to declare an extra variable*" you also don't need newlines or comments, either but it makes the code easier to read, understand and later debug.

Comment: I know, its just a way of few

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the return value of `toFixed()`.

```
num = parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);
num *= multiplyBy;
elements[i].innerHTML = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so in the following manner:

```js
var multiplyBy = 10;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.multiplyit');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let num = parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML)
  num *= multiplyBy
  elements[i].innerHTML = num.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<b class="multiplyit">0.69</b>
<b class="multiplyit">22.42</b>
```